# Raycaster Set getting Z value for respective XY

Tags: three.js

I have array of XY coordinates from which i have to get the respective Z positions. I have created the following code to achieve same.

This function loops through array and calls further function to get the Z value.

```
   function generate_section(){


        for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){

            //temporary try to get for the same.
                var pts = points[i];

                var z = sectioncall(pts.x,pts.y);


                console.log(pts,z);

        }
    }
```

The following function is a raycaster which cast the ray for the provided x& y value and cast a downward ray.

```
function sectioncall(x,y){  //grabs the Z value for the provided XY
        var top = new THREE.Vector3(x, y , 30 );
        var bottom = new THREE.Vector3(x  , y , -30 );
        var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
        direction = direction.subVectors( bottom, top ).normalize();
        //start raycaster

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

        raycaster.set( top, direction );

        // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
        var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObjects(scene.getObjectByName('MyObj_s').children);

        var rpt = intersects[0].point;

        //draw a line the way ray caster casting the ray
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices.push( top );
        geometry.vertices.push( rpt );
        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );
        var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
        scene.add( line );

        return rpt;

    }
```

With the above code i get the result like this:
[image]

but what i want to achive is the result like this:
[image]

So that the returning values will be about for respective XY instead of last XY as you see on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have slightly made a mistake in the code. 
it should be

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.getObjectByName('MyObj_s').children);
```

you misspelled it as rayCaster.